# Bulk convert binary data to decimal

Tags: cmd, binary, decimal, data-conversion

Does anyone know of a way - like a cmd script - able to convert between 1 gb and 10 gb of binary data into decimal ?

Here are the first 100 characters: **1000110101100100111101011000010100110001011110001101101110000011001000011010110111100110100100111111 ...**

1 - What I need is a way to first select 4 character strings and delete the ones that later on will output 0 or numbers bigger than 9 after the conversion.

```
1000 -> (8)
1101 -> (13) = delete
0110 -> (6)
0100 -> (4)
1111 -> (15) = delete
0101 -> (5)
1000 -> (8)
0101 -> (5)
0011 -> (3)
0001 -> (1)
0111 -> (7)
1000 -> (8)
1101 -> (13) = delete
1011 -> (11) = delete
1000 -> (8)
0011 -> (3)
0010 -> (2)
0001 -> (1)
1010 -> (10) = delete
1101 -> (13) = delete
1110 -> (14) = delete
0110 -> (6)
1001 -> (9)
0011 -> (3)
1111 -> (15) = delete
...
```

After this process the file original_binary_data.txt must contain no 4 character strings that output 0 or numbers bigger than 9 exactly like this:

**10000110010001011000010100110001011110001000001100100001011010010011 ...**

2 - After that step, I would like to convert the binary data to decimal data.
If we take the example above, then the result would be something like:

```
1000 -> 8
0110 -> 6
0100 -> 4
0101 -> 5
1000 -> 8
0101 -> 5
0011 -> 3
0001 -> 1
0111 -> 7
1000 -> 8
1000 -> 8
0011 -> 3
0010 -> 2
0001 -> 1
0110 -> 6
1001 -> 9
0011 -> 3
...
```

This should result in the file converted_decimal_data.txt containing something like:

**86458531788321693 ...**

Note: There are no other characters besides '0' or '1' in the binary data file.

The reason I need to do this is because I need huge quantities of random data comprehending between 1-9 to do an important experiment.

Comment: No need to delete an "old" post and post it again...

Comment: 16 string compares ? It's gigabytes of information... If you no how tell me how...

Comment: would external tools be ok? Doing this in batch seems... wrong

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Would definitley be quicker and better, but with a quick google search I cannot find a tool which can convert a very large (.txt) file to decimal - and those programs I didn't find need a filter, too...

Comment: Everything is ok for me. I only require that an answer comes with a step by step explanation of how to implement things in the case of an algorithm. I also accept any software capable to do this in a windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tested and working solution for PowerShell (which is ~200 times faster than the batch solution):

```cs
#################################################################################################################
#
# Converts 4 digit binary strings to decimal while sorting out all strings which equal 0 or are greater than 9.
#
# Adjust the source directory and input and output file names (files don't have to be .txt files).
#
$source = "C:\adjust\path"
$input_file = "file_name.extension"
$dec_output = "dec_output.txt"
$bin_output = "bin_output.txt"
#
#
# Using Get-Content on an input file with a size of 1GB or more will cause System.OutOfMemoryExceptions,
# therefore a large file gets temporarily split up.
#
$split_size = 100MB
$echo_ss = $split_size/1MB
#
#
# This adds carriage returns to the temporary file after each 16'384th character. Although the sweet spot is
# somewhere around 18'000 characters, the line length needs to be dividable by 4 and at best fit exactly n times
# into the temporary file; using 16'384 or characters (that is exactly 16 KB) ensures that.
#
$line_length = 16384
#
#
# Thanks @BenN (https://superuser.com/a/1292916/868077)
# Thanks @Bob (https://superuser.com/a/1295082/868077)
#################################################################################################################

Set-Location $source

if (Test-Path $bin_output) {

    $name = (Get-Item $bin_output).Basename
    $ext = (Get-Item $bin_output).Extension
    $num = 1

    while ($num -le 9999) {

        $test = $name+"_"+$num+$ext

        if (Test-Path $test) {

            $num += 1

        } else {

            break

        }

    }

    Rename-Item $bin_output $test
    $a = "`n`n Renamed 'bin_output'!"

}

if (Test-Path $dec_output) {

    $name = (Get-Item $dec_output).Basename
    $ext = (Get-Item $dec_output).Extension
    $num = 1

    while ($num -le 9999) {

        $test = $name+"_"+$num+$ext

        if (Test-Path $test) {

            $num += 1

        } else {

            break

        }

    }

    Rename-Item $dec_output $test
    $b = "`n`n Renamed 'dec_output'!"

}

if (Test-Path ".\_temp") {

    "`n"

    while ($overwrite -ne "true" -and $overwrite -ne "false") {

        $overwrite = Read-Host ' Splitted files already/still exists! Delete and recreate?'

        if ($overwrite -match "y") {

            $overwrite = "true"
            Remove-Item .\_temp -force -recurse
            $c = " Deleted existing splitted files and creating new ones!"

        } elseif ($overwrite -match "n") {

            $overwrite = "false"

        } elseif ($overwrite -match "c") {

            exit

        } else {

            "`n"
            Write-Host " Error: Invalid input!" "`n" " Type 'y' for 'yes'." " Type 'n' for 'no'." " Type 'c' for 'cancel'."
            "`n"
            "`n"

        }

    }

}

Clear-Host

"`n"

while ($delete -ne "true" -and $delete -ne "false") {

    $delete = Read-Host ' Delete splitted files afterwards?'

    if ($delete -match "y") {

        $delete = "true"
        $d = "`n`n Splitted files will be deleted afterwards!"

    } elseif ($delete -match "n") {

        $delete = "false"
        $d = "`n`n Splitted files will not be deleted afterwards!"

    } elseif ($delete -match "c") {

        exit

    } else {

            "`n"
            Write-Host " Error: Invalid input!" "`n" " Type 'y' for 'yes'." " Type 'n' for 'no'." " Type 'c' for 'cancel'."
            "`n"
            "`n"

    }

}

Clear-Host

"`n"; "`n"; "`n"; "`n"; "`n"; "`n"

$a
$b
$d

$start_o = (Get-Date)

if ($overwrite -ne "false") {

    $c
    "`n"
    $start = Get-Date
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ".\_temp" >$null 2>&1
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
    $bytes = New-Object byte[] 4096
    $in_file = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($input_file)
    $file_count = 0
    $finished = $false

    if ((Get-Item $input_file).length -gt $split_size) {

        Write-Host " Input file larger than $echo_ss MB!"
        Write-Host "     Splitting input file and inserting carriage returns..."
        $v=([MATH]::Floor([decimal]((Get-Item $input_file).Length/100MB)))
        $sec_rem = -1

        while (!$finished) {

            $perc = [MATH]::Round($file_count/$v*100)
            $file_count++
            $bytes_to_read = $split_size
            $out_file = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ".\_temp\_temp_$file_count.tmp",CreateNew,Write,None

            while ($bytes_to_read) {

                $bytes_read = $in_file.Read($bytes, 0, [Math]::Min($bytes.Length, $bytes_to_read))

                if (!$bytes_read) {

                    $finished = $true
                    break

                }

                $bytes_to_read -= $bytes_read
                $out_file.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes_read)

            }

            if (($i = $file_count-1) -gt 0) {

                (Get-Content ".\_temp\_temp_$i.tmp") -Replace ".{$line_length}", "$&`r`n" | Set-Content ".\_temp\_temp_$i.tmp"

            }

            $out_file.Dispose()
            $sec_elaps = (Get-Date) - $start
            $sec_rem = ($sec_elaps.TotalSeconds/$file_count) * ($v-$file_count+1)
            Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "Splitting input file and inserting carriage returns..." -Status "Progress ($perc%):" -PercentComplete ($perc) -SecondsRemaining $sec_rem

        }

        $in_file.Dispose()
        (Get-Content ".\_temp\_temp_$file_count.tmp") -Replace ".{$line_length}", "$&`r`n" | Set-Content ".\_temp\_temp_$file_count.tmp"
        Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity null -Completed

    } else {

        if ((Get-Item $input_file).length -lt $split_size) {

            " Input file smaller than $echo_ss MB!"

        } else {

            " Input file exactly $echo_ss MB!"

        }

        Write-Host "  Inserting carriage returns..."
        (Get-Content $input_file) -Replace ".{$line_length}", "$&`r`n" | Set-Content ".\_temp\_temp_1.tmp"; $file_count = 1

    }

    $dur = (Get-Date) - $start
    Write-Host "`n     Done! Duration:"$dur.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
    "`n"

} else {

    "`n"
    Write-Host " Continuing with existing files..."
    "`n"
    Get-ChildItem ".\_temp\*" -File -Include *.tmp | ForEach-Object -Process {$file_count++}

}

Write-Host " Converting binary into decimal..."
$sec_rem = -1
$start = Get-Date

Get-ChildItem ".\_temp\*" -File -Include *.tmp | ForEach-object -Process {

    $cur_file++
    $line_count = (Get-Content ".\_temp\_temp_$cur_file.tmp").count

    ForEach ($line in Get-Content ".\_temp\_temp_$cur_file.tmp") {

        $cur_line++
        $perc = [MATH]::Round(($cur_file-1+($cur_line/$line_count))/$file_count*100)
        $n = 0

        if ($line.length -ge 4) {

            while ($n -lt $line.length) {

                $dec = 0
                $bin = $line.substring($n,4)
                $dec = ([Convert]::ToInt32($bin,2))

                if ($dec -gt 0 -and $dec -le 9) {

                    $temp_dec = "$temp_dec$dec"
                    $temp_bin = "$temp_bin$bin"

                }

                $n += 4

            }

        $temp_dec | Add-Content $dec_output -Encoding ascii -NoNewline
        $temp_bin | Add-Content $bin_output -Encoding ascii -NoNewline
        Clear-Variable -Name "temp_dec", "temp_bin"

        }

        $sec_elaps = (Get-Date) - $start
        $sec_rem = ($sec_elaps.TotalSeconds/($cur_file-1+($cur_line/$line_count))) * ($file_count-($cur_file-1+($cur_line/$line_count)))
        Write-Progress -ID 2 -Activity "Converting binary into decimal..." -Status "Progress ($perc%):" -PercentComplete ($perc) -SecondsRemaining $sec_rem -CurrentOperation "Current file: '_temp_$cur_file.tmp'"

    }

    Clear-Variable -Name "cur_line"

}

Write-Progress -Activity null -Completed
$dur = (Get-Date) - $start
Write-Host "`n     Done! Duration:"$dur.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
"`n"

if ($delete -eq "true") {

    Remove-Item ".\_temp" -Force -Recurse

}

"`n"
"`n"
Write-Host " Script finished!" 
Write-Host "     Start time:   "$start_o.ToString("dd\.MM\.yyyy\ hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
Write-Host "     End time:     "(Get-Date).ToString("dd\.MM\.yyyy\ hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
$dur = (Get-Date) - $start_o
Write-Host "`n     Duration:     "$dur.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")
"`n`n`n"

Pause
Exit
```

This script needs a minute for 10 MB or about 100 minutes for 1 GB (that's **200 times faster** than the batch solution)!

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A tested, working and unpractical, but about 3 times faster batch solution (than the previous batch version):

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
TITLE Converting binary to decimal...
COLOR 0B

REM *********************************************

REM Set source directory!
SET "source=C:\adjust\path"

REM Set source file
SET "file_name=adjust_name.extension"

REM *********************************************


CD %source%

IF EXIST binary_output.txt SET "bin_exist=binary_output.txt " && SET "exist_and=and "
IF EXIST decimal_output.txt SET "dec_exist=decimal_output.txt" && SET "dec_exist_i=%exist_and%decimal_output.txt "

IF NOT "%bin_exist%"=="" (CALL :choice) ELSE (IF NOT "%dec_exist%"=="" CALL :choice)
CLS

powershell -Command "& {$B=$Env:file_name; (gc $B) -replace '.{4}' , """"$&`r`n"""" | sc temp.txt}"


SET time_short=%TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%
ECHO.
ECHO  %time_short%:
ECHO  Converting binary to decimal...
SET "startTime=%time: =0%"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (temp.txt) DO (
    SET "line=%%G"
    CALL :check_line
)

CALL :log_dec
CALL :duration
DEL temp.txt >nul
ECHO.
ECHO  Done^^! & ECHO. & ECHO  Duration: %hh:~1%%time:~2,1%%mm:~1%%time:~2,1%%ss:~1% & ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT


:check_line
IF "!line!"=="" EXIT /B

SET "char1=!line:~0,1!
SET "char2=!line:~1,1!
SET "char3=!line:~2,1!
SET "char4=!line:~3,1!

SET "decimal=0"
IF %char4%==1 SET /A "decimal=1"
IF %char3%==1 SET /A "decimal=%decimal%+2"
IF %char2%==1 SET /A "decimal=%decimal%+4"
IF %char1%==1 SET /A "decimal=%decimal%+8"

IF %decimal% EQU 0 EXIT /B
IF %decimal% GTR 9 EXIT /B

SET "binary_output=!binary_output!%line%"
SET "decimal_output=!decimal_output!%decimal%"

SET /A "line_number=%line_number%+1"
IF !line_number!==2043 CALL :log_bin
IF !line_number!==4086 CALL :log_bin
IF !line_number!==6129 CALL :log_bin
IF !line_number!==8172 CALL :log_dec
EXIT /B

:log_bin
SET /P "=!binary_output!" <nul >> "%source%\binary_output.txt"
SET "binary_output="
EXIT /B

:log_dec
SET /P "=!binary_output!" <nul >> "%source%\binary_output.txt"
SET /P "=!decimal_output!" <nul >> "%source%\decimal_output.txt"
SET "binary_output=" & SET "decimal_output=" & SET "line_number=0"
EXIT /B


:duration
SET "endTime=%time: =0%"
SET "end=!endTime:%time:~8,1%=%%100)*100+1!"  &  SET "start=!startTime:%time:~8,1%=%%100)*100+1!"
SET /A "elap=((((10!end:%time:~2,1%=%%100)*60+1!%%100)-((((10!start:%time:~2,1%=%%100)*60+1!%%100)"
SET /A "cc=elap%%100+100,elap/=100,ss=elap%%60+100,elap/=60,mm=elap%%60+100,hh=elap/60+100"
EXIT /B


:choice
ECHO. & ECHO  %bin_exist%%dec_exist_i%already exists^^! & ECHO.
CHOICE /C RDC /N /M "[R]ename / [D]elete / [C]ancle"
IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 DEL %bin_exist%%dec_exist%
IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 CALL :rename
EXIT /B

:rename
IF NOT "%bin_exist%"=="" (
    IF EXIST binary_output_*.txt (
        FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR binary_output_*.txt /B /O:N') DO (
            SET "file_name=%%~nA"
            SET "file_num_1=!file_name:binary_output_=!
            SET /A "file_num_1=!file_num_1!+1"
        )
        REN binary_output.txt binary_output_!file_num_1!.txt
    ) ELSE (REN binary_output.txt binary_output_1.txt)
)

IF "%dec_exist%"=="" EXIT /B
IF EXIST decimal_output_*.txt (
    FOR /F %%B IN ('DIR decimal_output_*.txt /B /O:N') DO (
        SET "file_name=%%~nB"
        SET "file_num_2=!file_name:decimal_output_=!
        SET /A "file_num_2=!file_num_2!+1"
    )
    REN decimal_output.txt decimal_output_!file_num_2!.txt
) ELSE (REN decimal_output.txt decimal_output_1.txt)
EXIT /B
```

This will create a temporary file to read from (`temp.txt`), a binary output file (`binary_output.txt`) and a decimal output file (`decimal_output.txt`).

When the script finished `temp.txt` will get deleted - or maybe I should say "**if** the script finishes":

I mean... for a simple `.txt` file with a size of 80KB this script needed just under 1.5 minutes; thus a 1GB file would take around 315h - or **13 days!**

This is probably not the perfect batch solution, but if you have to convert files with a size of 10GB then even the perfect batch solution will take days (if not weeks or even months) to process the nearly **11 billion `0`'s and `1`'s**
(10GB are exactly 10'737'418'240 Bytes).

---

I don't know what you need this for and maybe you have a machine running 24/7/365 which could convert even 10GB files, but if you need the results within this decade or so you should probably look for a non-batch solution...

However, if one doesn't consider time as a factor, this is very much a working solution! :)

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*I used always the same CPU while it was idle. All times may vary quite a lot on different systems!*

**CPU used:** i7-4820K @3.70GHz (Quad-core)

Also: thanks [@BenN](https://superuser.com/users/380318/ben-n) and [@Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) for helping me out [here](https://superuser.com/a/1292916/868077) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1295082/868077)!

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Edit (08/02/18):

Added a faster solution and a small interface.

Instead of adding each 4 digit binary string directly to the output file they now are added to a variable until this variable reaches 8172 characters and then said variable is added to the output file. This results in a nearly 3 times faster process (durations above have already been adjusted)!

Why 8172? Because 8174 is the limit for a var (set in a batch on Windows 10, don't know for sure about other Windows versions), but isn't dividable by 4 so the last binary string wouldn't be completley added to the output file. Obviously, before reaching line 8172 the binary output variable would be 4 times over it's limit (actually 4 times minus 2 lines), so said variable is added every 2043rd line.

---

### Edit (12/02/18):

Added solution for PowerShell 5.0.

I also figured, that it'd be smart to add which CPU I have as both scripts (apparently) depend very much on CPU speed and/or cores.

---

### Edit (12/02/18):

Added solution for PowerShell 4.0 and lower as the `-NoNewline` option for `Out-File` was introduced in PowerShell 5.0.

---

### Edit (16/02/18):

Added support for files with a size of 1GB or more, after I was running into `System.OutOfMemoryException`s whenever trying to use `Get-Content` on a file with a size of 1GB (or more).

Added a small interface for the PowerShell solution.

Changed `Out-File` to `Add-Content` as it comes with a `-NoNewline` option since PowerShell 4.0 and with that got rid of 1 extra PowerShell solution.

---

### Edit (19/02/18)

Fixed an issue where files would get deleted before being processed.

---

### Edit (20/02/18)

Improved interface. Added progress bar with estimated remaining time and possibility to convert existing files.

Changed variable `$input` to `$input_file`.

---

### Edit (20/02/18)

Fixed a bug where `Write-Progress` wouldn't work with single files.

---

### Edit (03/03/18)

Added option to keep splitted files.

Improved overall formatting.

Comment: Did some testing: - overall time: 4:30 - without binary output: 2:45 - without binary and decimal output: 1:30 - without any output (including echo): 1:15

Comment: I will test this now. I only got some time to do it now... It's more important to me to at least get a decimal output. At least one time... But a good answer would do both things. This so that I'am able to generate random data whenever I want.

Comment: @FábioLinhares I found a quicker batch solution (~3 times faster), working it out right now for maximum speed.

Comment: @FábioLinhares How so?

Comment: @FábioLinhares I chose 8184 characters per line as 8186 is not dividable by 4... ;) (But the faster solution will have one 4 digit string on each line (about ~10% faster, as no 2nd (`FOR`) loop is required).

Comment: Ok, I'm back in business :) The script is working. I have tested with a file with 114 kb... It took a minute. Well done! Now I only need a faster script. Yes you're right I read that already :)

Comment: The newline is not being saved to the file right ? It's only being managed in the script, right ? I tried to search for it (\n) in notepad ++ but didn't find it... which is a good thing...

Comment: `SET /P "=%var%" <nul >> log.txt` will add `%var%` to `log.txt` wihtout an(y) (addtitional) carriage return(s). So, yes, no new line is created.

Comment: Ok. So now to be able to run all that data I can 'cut the the original file in pieces' of 8184 and run the script in each one of them, or find a way to run in the 1 GB+ file...

Comment: This is so close. Can you do it all in one script ? Dividing the original file in 8184 size, than generate all the data to 2 files binary and decimal, and in the end joint the original file again ? That would be awesome! I think that that would do the trick... Because it automated the whole process and in the end it will be the same thing as it if it was doing from the big original file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164778/discussion-between-fatalbullethit-and-fabio-linhares).

Comment: Thanks a lot @FatalBulletHit you're awesome!

Comment: @FábioLinhares Updated the script , see "Edit" paragraph. :)

Comment: .@FatalBulletHit if you do that split thing I will actually choose this as the right answer... I think I could do it, but I trust you more :p And would take more time to do...

Comment: I didn't quite  understand this part in edit: "Obviously, before reaching line 8172 the binary output variable would be 4 times over it's limit (actually 4 times minus 2 lines), so said variable is added every 2043rd line."

Comment: @FatalBulletHit: I'm a complete Powershell novice, but I feel something like `-replace '(.{4})' , [Convert]::ToInt32('$1', 2)` instead of `-replace '.{4}' , """"$&`r`n""""`should work. (and be much faster than batch). Sadly, I can't get it to work and can't figure out, why.

Comment: @Stephan I don't know anything about PowerShell, but, yes, it'd most likely be faster...

Comment: @Stephan Feel free to look at my first PowerShell script... :D

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted any code of your own. This seemed like an interesting problem, but the pretense seems dubious. It would be questionable to do this in a cmd.exe script. Most likely, PowerShell, Python, Perl, or another language would be more appropriate.

This will probably not be the fastest implementation, but this PowerShell script seems to work.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    # The path to the file you want to read.
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $InFile

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $OutFile
)

$digits = "0123456789"

if (Test-Path -Path $InFile) {
    try {
        $resolvedPath = Resolve-Path -Path $InFile

        $fileStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList ($resolvedPath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
        $fileReader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.BinaryReader -ArgumentList $fileStream
        $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $OutFile

        [byte[]]$abytes = $fileReader.ReadBytes(1)
        while ($abytes.length -ne 0) {
            [byte]$abyte = $abytes[0]
            [System.Byte[]]$outbytes = @()

            Write-Verbose "Got byte ===$abyte==="
            $high = $abyte -shr 4
            Write-Verbose "High is ===$high==="
            if ($high -lt 10) { $outbytes += $digits[$high] }

            $low = $abyte -band 0x0F
            Write-Verbose "Low is ===$low==="
            if ($low -lt 10) { $outbytes += $digits[$low] }

            $stream.Write([char[]]$outbytes)

            [byte[]]$abytes = $fileReader.ReadBytes(1)
        }

    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }

    finally {
        $stream.close()
        $fileReader.Dispose()
        $fileStream.Dispose()
    }
} else {
    Write-Warning "$Path not found!"
}
```

Save this code in a file with a `.ps1` extension. Perhaps myconvert.ps1. Then, run it from PowerShell.

```
.\myconvert.ps1 .\infile.txt .\outfile.txt
```

If you must run it from a cmd.exe shell.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ".\myconvert.ps1 .\infile.txt .\outfile.txt"
```

**EDIT** Here is an example of using it.

```
C:>type readnibbles.txt
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command "Format-Hex -Path .\readnibbles.txt"

           Path: C:\src\t\readnibbles.txt

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 70  abcdefghijklmnop
00000010   71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 0D 0A              qrstuvwxyz..


C:>powershell -NoProfile -Command ".\readnibbles.ps1 .\readnibbles.txt .\readnibbles-out.txt"

C:>type readnibbles-out.txt
61626364656667686966666670717273747576777879700
```

Comment: I never worked with PowerShell, Python, or Perl, so it would probably harder for me to implement... In the case of this script, what is the file extension where I put this code ? Is it name.ps1 ? Do I put the location where it says "# The path to the file you want to read." ? Is it something like straight "C:/..." ?

Comment: What about the file path in the script ?

Comment: I am not sure I know what "file path in the script" is referring to. Which line of code?

Comment: The script is now runing but i've opened the outfile.txt with 1mb and later with 3 mb generated and it seems to be printing this: 3130303031313031303131303031303031313131303130 :s Now with 5 mb I've stoped the script... It only prints that.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show an example of usage. It processes a string of a-z characters. Do you agree that is working as expected?

Comment: The data of input must be binary data. The data of output must be 1 to 9 decimal characters. Maybe some work on the script is needed...

Comment: If you have a better solution in other languages its fine for me, the only thing I will need is for you to explain me exactly how I should proceed so that I can implement things correctly.

Comment: @FábioLinhares I've something in batch, but I can't get it quite to work (conversion is working, but batch cannot handle more than 8186 characters in a single line and something in my `FOR` loop isn't working as it should)...

Comment: Hum... I'm starting to think that this wont be an easy job! If you guys can't do it but know someone who can, I think that you guys can let them know about this question. I think this question might actually be useful for a lot of people in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). Python is a light-weight, interpreted language with an easy-going syntax (once you get past the Tabs vs. Space thing ), and as it gets run in efficient bytecode, it's still pretty fast. Its interpreted nature is perfect for trying things inside its built-in console, and you can use any plain text editor to write and edit larger programs.

After creating a 10MB large 'random' file of 0's and 1's, I interactively explored what you would need for your task. This 7-liner is what I ended up with. It opens one file for input, one for output (they do not need explicit *closing* using this syntax) and reads batches of 4 characters from the input until an end-of-file is encountered. The 4 binary characters are converted into an integer and if it's between your desired values, writes it into the output file.

```python
with open('original_binary_data.txt','r') as f_read:
    with open('converted_decimal_data.txt','w') as f_write:
        while True:
            a = f_read.read(4)
            if not a: break
            b = int(a,2)
            if b > 0 and b < 10: f_write.write(str(b))
```

and it takes about 5 seconds of user time to go through my 10MB sample. Extrapolating for 1GB of data¹, that would take 100 * 5 secs or ~ 8 minutes.

It may be possible to significantly slash this time; reading and writing larger buffers might be worth looking in to. However, I guess that will take more than 8 minutes of your time to get it right. If you are not looking forward to processing a 10GB file (which would take around 1.5 hours), you could spend some time trying it out.

Or run this as-is during lunch break.

<sup>¹ Well ... assuming reading and writing scale O(n), which may not be true on your (or *any*) system. I am not going to create such a huge dummy file just to see if it does.</sup>